# SQL query syntax error in lambda function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

I have a written a delete method in lambda using node.js but when I run the method it gives an error **You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

here is my code

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({ //  a connection pool is a cache of database connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when future requests to the database are required
   host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
   user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
   password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
   port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
  database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);
  let CategoryId = event['categoryId'];
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
 context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
         let sql ="UPDATE ctrData2.WrapupCodes  SET CategoryId=null where CategoryId=?;";
        let field = [CategoryId];
    connection.query(sql,field, function (err, result, field) {
      if (err) throw err;
      // console.log(result);
      connection.release();
       console.log(typeof(result.affectedRows));
      let affectedRows = result.affectedRows;
      if(result && affectedRows > 0){
      let response ={
             status: "200",
             message:"Data bas been deleted successfully"
          };
          console.log(response);
          callback(null,response);
      }else{
            callback(null,{
              status: 404,
              message: "Id not found"
            });
          }
    });
    let sql1 = "delete from ctrData2.Category where CategoryId=?";
        let fields = [CategoryId];
            connection.query(sql1,fields, function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
      // console.log(result);
      connection.release();
       console.log(typeof(result.affectedRows));
      let affectedRows = result.affectedRows;
      if(result && affectedRows > 0){
      let response ={
             status: "200",
             message:"Data bas been deleted successfully"
          };
          console.log(response);
          callback(null,response);
      }else{
            callback(null,{
              status: 404,
              message: "Id not found"
            });
          }

});
    
  });
};
```

I don't know what is this error about the query is running successfully in MySQL Workbench but here it gives an error please help me to find an error.

Comment: you have 2 ? in your query; but you only have one field specified.

Comment: @ewong i did with 2 also but still same error

Comment: @ewong like this **let field = [CategoryId, CategoryId];** but still syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have field and fields

```
 let field = [CategoryId];
connection.query(sql,field, function (err, result, fields) ;
```

try

```
  let field = [CategoryId, CategoryId];
  connection.query(sql,field, function (err, result, field) ;
```

and could be you have can't execute multi queries

```
let sql ="UPDATE ctrData2.WrapupCodes  SET CategoryId=null where CategoryId=?;";
let field = [CategoryId];
connection.query(sql,field, function (err, result, field) {
  ...
}

let sql = "delete from ctrData2.Category where CategoryId=?";
let field = [CategoryId];
connection.query(sql,field, function (err, result, field) {
  ...
}
```

and try not using using backtics